# Flux of a vectioral field across a sphere for $r \to 0^+$

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

It's given the vectorial field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ of class $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let be $\phi (r)$ its outgoing flux across the sphere centered in $(0,0,0)$ and with radius $r>0$. Then for $r \to 0^+$, to what tends $\phi(r)$?

Comment: definition of $\operatorname{div}\vec{F}$....

Comment: Ok I have to use the Gauss Theorem, so I have to use $div \vec{F}$, but how?

Answer (score 0):

There are an $R>0$ and an $M>0$ such that $$|{\bf F}({\bf x})|\leq M\qquad  \bigl(|{\bf x}|\leq R\bigr)\ .$$ For $0<r<R$ then one has $$\phi(r)=\int_{\partial B_r}{\bf F}({\bf x})\cdot{\bf n}({\bf x})\>{\rm d}\omega$$
and therefore
$$|\phi(r)|\leq M \cdot4\pi r^2\qquad(r<R)\ .$$
It follows that $\lim_{r\to0+}\phi(r)=0$.